# Automating user action on iPhone using a script

Tags: ios, automation, user-input

I have developed an iPhone application that requires user action to select an option from a pop-up list. This list is generated by the OS and not by the application. I was wondering if there is a way to write and run the script to automate the user action when this list appears.. Is there a facility (a script/ third-part service etc) to do something like this in iOS apps? Also, I am looking for solutions not limited to testing environments. Please advice..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The only way to do that in a *proper* way would be using `UIAutomation`, `KIF` or similar integration test environments.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that using Apple's framework, mainly because, if you could, you'd be able to potentially do *anything* with the iPhone without the user's permission.

If your app is not supposed to go in the App Store, then maybe there's a way, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Hmm..Agree to what you say. I do want to distribute it legally so no private apis, jail-breaking etc.. thanks for the answer.